# SQL Update table with counter

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a column in a table with the next number.

Here is an example:

Table1

```
User1    100
User2    101
User3    102
User4    NULL
User5    NULL
User6    NULL
```

I need it to go to

```
User1  100
User2  101
User3  102
User4  103
User5  104
User6  105
```

I have tried a couple things like:

```
update Table1
set EmpID = MAX(empid)+1
where UserName = null
```

but that would just set all the nulls to 103.

Comment: Which SQL engine? MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, other? And what is 1., 2., 3., 4... - is it ID field or something?

Comment: How do you know what order you want the users to be numbered by? Alphabetically?

Answer (score 5):

If using **MS SQL Server**, then a trick you can do is that you can update a row and set a variable in the same go, and then reuse the updated variable.

To illustrate, consider the following:

```
DECLARE @NextID INT
SET @NextID = 102

UPDATE Table1
 SET @NextID = EmpID = @NextID + 1
WHERE EmpID IS NULL
```

This sets an initial value to @NextId. You can populate it how suits your logic.
Then it runs an Update over Table1 and assigns @NextId + 1 into EmpID, for the first row that's updated, giving 103 in this example.
@NextId will then update to the value just used to assign into EmpId - again 103.
And so forth, so the subsequent rows will get 104 and then 105 and so on.

This way to update a variable and a row value in one go is extremely useful, and with a little modification to your specific problem, it should be applicable.

Answer (score 3):

If your db supports `row_number()` you can update null EmpId's to `row_number() + max(EmpId)`

```
update t1
set t1.EmpId = t2.rn
from Table1 t1 
join (select UserName,      
    row_number() over(partition by EmpId order by UserName) 
    + (select max(EmpId) from Table1) rn      
    from Table1 
    where EmpId is null) t2
on t1.UserName = t2.UserName
where t1.EmpId is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it with Postgres:

```
with numbered_users as (
   select username,
          empid,
          (select max(empid) from table1) as max_id,
          row_number() over (order by username) as rn
   from table1
   where empid is null
)
update table1 
   set empid = nu.max_id + nu.rn
from numbered_users nu
where nu.username = table1.username 
   and table1.empid is null
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
UPDATE [Table1] SET [EmpID ] = [EmpID] +1 WHERE [UserName] = N'User1'
```

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one, but I doubt it will work.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET
    EmpID = (SELECT MAX(EmpID) FROM Table1)+1
WHERE EmpID IS NULL
```

You really have to tell us more about your requirement. See my comment above.

Comment: This will update all rows with the same value, not with an incrementing value (and it won't work on MySQL due to it's stupid sub-select limitations)